# Flex to access a public calendar using Google API without OAuth

Tags: api, apache-flex, calendar

I am trying to access the public holidays calendar using Google API. I read from some Q&A stackoverflow that accessing public calendars do not need authorization and with an API key I can retrieve all the holidays of a particular country. Below is an URL that I entered in web browser and be able to dump all the holidays without OAuth. https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.canadian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=myAPIkey
Replacing myAPIkey with the API key generated by google will give me all the Canadian holidays dumped in the browser.
So, I wrote the below Flex program but the returned evt.result contains no data. I tried different calendarService.resultFormat but still none works. Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="doInit()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.rpc.Responder;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

            private var calendarService:HTTPService;
            private var success:Boolean = true;

            protected function doInit():void
            {
                calendarService = new HTTPService();
                calendarService.method = "GET";
                //calendarService.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_ARRAY;
                //calendarService.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_E4X;
                calendarService.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_FLASHVARS;
                //calendarService.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_OBJECT;
                //calendarService.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_TEXT;
                //calendarService.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_XML;
            }

            public function getCalendarByCountry():void
            {   
                calendarService.url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.canadian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=<myAPIkey>";
                respCalendar.token = calendarService.send();
                respCalendar.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onCalendarsResponse);
                respCalendar.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, onCalendarsFault);
            }

            private function onCalendarsResponse(evt:ResultEvent):void
            {
                respCalendar.removeEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onCalendarsResponse);
                success = true;
            }


        private function onCalendarsFault(evt:FaultEvent):void
        {
            respCalendar.removeEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onCalendarsFault);
            success = false;
        }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <mx:CallResponder id="respCalendar"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:Button label="Get" click="getCalendarByCountry()"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: What do you mean with no data? is it null? or is it an empty String? Try adding the fault listener and see if that provides some clarity. And are you sure you want RESULT_FORMAT_OBJECT: The result format "object" specifies that the value returned is XML but is parsed as a tree of ActionScript objects.

Comment: It is null. Added fault listener but never executed. No particular reason to have RESULT_FORMAT_OBJECT, I just follow the https://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/tag/flex-code-for-google-calendar/ which I know is outdated. Modified to use RESULT_FORMAT_FLASHVARS and this time the evt.token.result is an object and it has all the information of Canadian holidays that I asked for. It looks like a JSON object except that it is a continuous text with \n and unwanted double qoutes like this {\n "kind": "calendar#events",\n "summary": "Holidays in Canada", How to have google to pass real JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the resultFormat to HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_TEXT and use JSON.parse() on the evt.result.

More info about JSON.parse() here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html